# Web scraping: HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden, python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

Hi I am need to scrape web page end extract data-id use Regular expression

Here is my code :

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("https://clarity-project.info/tenders/?entity=38163425&offset=100")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
DataId = bsObg.findAll("data-id", {"skr":re.compile("data-id=[0-9,a-f]")})
for DataId in DataId:
    print(DataId["skr"])
```

when I run my program in `Jupyter` :

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: you have got three answers on your question. What I can understand based on your comment below is that you have got it solved already. Why didn't you mark that as your answer? Do you actually know how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the web server is asking you to authenticate before serving content to Python's urllib. However, they serve everything neatly to `wget` and `curl` and https://clarity-project.info/robots.txt doesn't seem to exist, so I reckon scraping as such is fine with them. Still, it might be a good idea to ask them first.

As for the code, simply changing the User Agent string to something they like better seems to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

request = Request(
    'https://clarity-project.info/tenders/?entity=38163425&offset=100',
    headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0'})

html = urlopen(request).read().decode()
```

(unrelated, you have another mistake in your code: bsObj ≠ bsObg)

**EDIT** added code below to answer additional question from the comments:

What you seem to need is to find the value of the data-id attribute, no matter to which tag it belongs. The code below does just that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://clarity-project.info/tenders/?entity=38163425&offset=100'
agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36\
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'

request = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': agent})

html = urlopen(request).read().decode()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

tags = soup.findAll(lambda tag: tag.get('data-id', None) is not None)
for tag in tags:
    print(tag['data-id'])
```

The key is to simply use a `lambda` expression as the parameter to the `findAll` function of BeautifulSoup.

Comment: thank you!!! Maybe you can give me your advise? I have a web page 'clarity-project.info/tenders/…; and I need extract data-id="<some number>" and write in new file. I read a lot about web scrapping but I can't write right program. It is very important for me))

Comment: added to my original answer to do just that

Answer (score 2):

The server is likely blocking your requests because of the default user agent. You can change this so that you will appear to the server to be a web browser. For example, a Chrome User-Agent is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36
```

To add a User-Agent you can create a request object with the url as a parameter and the User-Agent passed in a dictionary as the keyword argument 'headers'.

See:

```
import urllib.request
r = urllib.request.Request(url, headers= {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'})
html = urllib.request.urlopen(r)
```

Comment: thank you!!! Maybe you can give me your advise? I have a web page 'clarity-project.info/tenders/…; and I need extract data-id="<some number>" and write in new file. I read a lot about web scrapping but I can't write right program. It is very important for me))

Comment: @kristinaSos Take a look at the documentation: http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ . Also, please select a best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 

url = 'your url here'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text,"html.parser")

for i in soup.find_all('tr', attrs={'class':'table-row'}):
    print '[Data id] => {}'.format(i.get('data-id'))
```

This should work!